# Intersection of two (or more) elastic indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two elasticsearch indices, one is for customers who bought item A, let's call it index_A, and similarly index_B.

Every record in these indices are transaction data, which has client_id and time_of_sale.

Every customer has an id (not the default _id field of elasticsearch)
I would like to find all customer_ids that are in both indices.

Right now I'm iterating through both (which is a huge pain), creating a list of all unique customer_ids for each index, and then finding the overlap in python.

Is there a better way? that doesn't iterate over all indices with match_all?

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this would be to query both indexes at the same time and producing aggregation keys made of the index name and the `client_id` and then aggregating on those keys. Since that would involve some scripting, and can thus harm performance, there is another way using pipeline aggregations.

Using the [`bucket_selector` pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html), you can first aggregate on `client_id` and then on the index name and only select those client buckets whcih contain (at least) two indexes:

```
POST index_*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "customers": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "client_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "indexes": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "_index",
            "size": 10
          }
        },
        "customers_in_both_indexes": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "nb_buckets": "indexes._bucket_count"
            },
            "script": "params.nb_buckets > 1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```